# Repeating adding columns as rows in DataFrame Python 2.7 Pandas 0.17.1

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes I would like to combine, but they don't share an index

The first has the following structure:

`date          mail_volume
 2011-01-01    100
 2011-02-01    150
 2011-03-01    125
 ...`

The second is created using the quantile function:

`df.quantile([.25,.50,.75])`

and has the structure of:

`mail_volume
 0.25    110
 0.50    120
 0.75    130`

I would like to create a third dataframe with the following structure where the quantile results get repeated for each month along with the original results:

`date          mail_volume    metric_type
 2011-01-01    100            result
 2011-01-01    110            .25
 2011-01-01    120            .50
 2011-01-01    130            .75
 2011-02-01    150            result
 2011-02-01    110            .25
 2011-02-01    120            .50
 2011-02-01    130            .75`

I have searched for appending and inserting rows to a dataframe, but those do not solve my issue due to the need to repeat the date and add the metric_type column.

Thanks in advance,
Eric

Comment: Can we join both data frames using mail_volume

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's do a cartesian merge and concat with original dataframe:

```
pd.concat([df.assign(metric_type='result'),
           df.assign(key=1).merge(df2.reset_index().assign(key=1), on='key', suffixes=('_x',''))[['date','mail_volume','index']].rename(columns={'index':'metric_type'})])\
  .sort_values(by='date')
```

Output:

```
       date  mail_volume metric_type
0  2011-01-01          100      result
0  2011-01-01          110        0.25
1  2011-01-01          120         0.5
2  2011-01-01          130        0.75
1  2011-02-01          150      result
3  2011-02-01          110        0.25
4  2011-02-01          120         0.5
5  2011-02-01          130        0.75
2  2011-03-01          125      result
6  2011-03-01          110        0.25
7  2011-03-01          120         0.5
8  2011-03-01          130        0.75
```